# How to load data from local Json file using http get?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to load data from local json file. I have provided the reference as shown below in screen shot. But when i run the app on localhost i get the error:
**404 not found**.

```
getMainCategory():Observable<MainCategory>{

  return this.http.get("./providers/mainCategory.json")
    .map(res=>res<MainCategory[]>(res.json().items))

}
```

[image: Code Descript]

Comment: check if your path is right

Comment: there's no screenshot

Comment: Please share the code if possible and missing the screenshot here

Comment: my bad.. let me edit question

Comment: hey try my answer, you just store data in variable and return that variable.

Comment: I want to load it from json file.

Comment: just give the path    ‘src/providers/mainCategory.json’

Comment: that too is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remember to inject $http. i have store json file in data folder

```
function loadBranch(){
        $http.get('data/branchList.json').success(function(response){

            vm.branchs = response;
        })
    }
```

**branchList.json**

```
[
  {
    "name":"sam"
  }
]
```

**NOTE:** check your json file path. i think your program couldn't able to get path

Comment: your code is not relevant to OP. Furthermore he has already injected http service. Its possibly his path problem

Comment: ya, i think his program couldn't able to get file

Comment: main problem is it cannot find the file on the path i provided.

Comment: could you please set absolute path for testing purpose, whether file is found or not

Comment: What do you mean sam ?

Comment: i mean you just put full system path, ex- `D://TECHINFO/src/providers/mainCategory.json`, check whether file found by your program or not.

Comment: It worked for me after i placed json file inside root folder www. Thanks for your suggestions..

Comment: so it is working when you put total path right ? if you put your `mainCategory.json` inside **app** folder then it will sure work, ex- `http.get("mainCategory.json")`. then no need to put absolute path.